Why would sperm cells derived from women's stem cells always produce female children?
Lore Background
The Scientocractic Hivemind has defied the heavenly balance of the Equilibrium Hivemind, realizing that its transcendental nature makes this an inevitability. Determined to upend the Equilibrium Hivemind's imposed 10 Gaianic Systems so that it can attempt to break through Rank 5, the Scientocratic HIvemind must begin eroding these 10, beginning with the Law of Yin and Yang.
All Hiveminds must have balanced Mankind and Womankind as dictated by the Law of Yin and Yang. To shake the Law, it refines a Hivemind comprised entirely of Womankind. With the lofty name of the Propagation Hivemind, she will reproduce through a perfected form of technology the Scientocratic Hivemind invented that converts stem cells to sperm cell. The derived sperm is suitable to produce viable human babies. Because of the sperm itself, every child produced is female.
Question
Why would sperm cells converted from the women's stem cells always produce female children? What would the science-based mechanism be?

They are human and are indistinguishable from normal people. The mental aspect of the Hivemind is supernatural therefore it's disconnected to the natural processes.
Ignore the backdrop of supernaturality, the conversion process itself is scientific in nature.
The babies born are completely healthy and viable. All are female.


Does the first paragraph add anything relevant to the question?

@zovits My question would probably get closed for being seen more as a Biology.SE post if I didn't include any worldbuilding context.

You likely don't even need spermatozoa. If you are going to inject the genetic data into a sperm cell to fertilize the egg, you might as well directly inject it into egg cell. It would mean you would need to create every baby in a lab, but the conversion to spermatozoa already meant that. This will also keeps procreation even further away from your yin-yang balance.

@vinzzz001: unless you want to do cloning, it's substantially easier to create sperm cells from stem cells (and stem cells from other cells) than it is to sidestep the fertilisation process. We're actually pretty close to being able to do it already - it's already been done in mice and we're close to have a viable process for humans.

-1, a cursory google search would answer this and more.

Biology for dummies:
Because of how sex determination works for humans, women carry XX chromosomes, men carry XY chromosomes.

No matter how hard you try, from a woman's cell you won't get a Y chromosome to make a man, therefore you will get only women.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
